# Scrapy - unable to hit the URL for webscraping

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to replicate the following scrapy tutorial - http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/07/scrapy-and-elasticsearch.html.

I get the following error trace while running the spider-

```
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),     scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-04-16 14:00:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-04-16 14:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying  <GET http://www.meetup.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times):   [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2018-04-16 14:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.meetup.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2018-04-16 14:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.meetup.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2018-04-16 14:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.meetup.com/robots.txt>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
  result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
  return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
```

Can someone kindly help me fix/understand the issue.

Comment: Do you have a proxy in your system

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cannot reach the destination address, what is the output of : wget http://www.meetup.com/robots.txt?

Anyway you are trying to reach the http endpoint while meetup has been upgraded to just https, try to change start_urls to https, like :

```
start_urls = [
    "https://www.meetup.com/Search-Meetup-Karlsruhe/"
]
```